# jquery return + strict warning function does not always return a value

Tags: jquery

I have the following line of JQUERY:

```
 if(html == 'html5' && pastURL == url) {return false;}
```

This is causing the function its within to show an error:

'strict warning function does not always return a value'.

Is there a way to alter this so it doesn't show this error and why is it showing this? Note:  don't have 'use strict;' in the code.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All functions must either have no `return` statement or their last executed line must be a return.  So if you're planning a route that will return false, make sure that the function always returns something no matter how that condition plays out.  The easiest way to do this is to put a return statement at the end of the function so that it will always return if it gets there.

Comment: ok... does that mean I would add a 'return true;' at the bottom? how would I ensure something is returned when I reallky don't hav anything to return?

Comment: @Adam yes, just add a return statement at the bottom.  You don't need to process it if it returns true, but the javascript won't compile if you don't have it.

Comment: worked fine adding return false; to the of the function.. thx... will tick when time is up...

Answer (score 1):

put and `else` statement and make it return.

Something like

```
 if(html == 'html5' && pastURL == url) {return false;} else {return true;}
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't remove the warning.